# angular $http returns internal server error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular.I have try to send $http request to server and return some values.This is my javascript

```
function loadCustomers() {
    var Location = {};
    Location.Setup_Location_Code = loggedLocation;
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: loadCustomerDetailsLink,
        data: $.param(Location),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    })
        .success(function (data) {
            alert("receved")
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            }
        }).error(function (data) {

        });
};
```

and this is my c# code

```
[HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult GetCustomerList(Customer_Details customer)
    {
        return Ok(DA_CustomerController.getCustomerList(customer.Setup_Location_Code));
    
    }
```

but browser shows this error for me
[image]
please help me to solve this

Comment: If it's an *internal server error*, shouldn't you look at the server side instead ?

Comment: @SarangaSachinthana I believe no need mention [HttpPost] just do change your action name to `PostCustomerList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your web api config like bellow

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your angular code is ok, but perhaps there's some issue in your c# code.
I think you should set return type by JsonResult and return Json data at the end.
Let's try this, it maybe help you.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: You should change the  method: 'GET' because you make a get request, url : loadCustomerDetailsLink + '/' + loggedLocation. public JsonResult GetCustomerList(String loggedLocation). return Json(DA_CustomerController.getCustomerList(loggedLocation), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: but i need to post value with the request

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. the webApiConfig should change like bellow

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// Simple POST request example (passing data) :
$http.post('/someUrl', {msg:'hello word!'}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

U have to call like this.....first parameter is url and second one is a object what ever u want to post..